# Moving CodeIgniter website over to a new domain but same host

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, ssl

I am moving over my web app to a new domain on the same host, I have edited the .htaccess file and now see a redirect loop. The new domain does not have HTTPS but the old domain had an SSL certificate. I want to use no SSL for the new domain. Here is what I have in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be able to comment out the `https` RewriteRule

Try changing

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

To

```
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Or keep a backup and delete those lines

Comment: But I want to keep the www infront of the domain? I am now seeing a page not found error :(

Comment: really want `www`? Easier for people to type address without it and can have a rule that sends `www` to non `www`

Comment: So I shouldn't add a rewritebase and add the new directory that the new files are in?

Comment: question made no mention of change in directory structure

Comment: Right now the site just goes to a page not found error

Comment: is your index.php in root?

Comment: When moving a site over do I need to edit any other files?

Comment: site is back online after your help but the database is not working

Comment: database name and  username and passwords the same?

Comment: yes, never touched the database, all I did was move over all the files into this new addon domain.

Comment: but if it's a different domain likely different database no?

Comment: all fixed, one of the core files was messed up. Thanks for your help!